# Value e ID no DropDown Cascata

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, dropdown

Referência que pode ajudar a entender o código.

[DropDown Cascata](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100716/dropdown-cascata)

Essa parte aqui eu passo os valores que vai ser adicionado no segundo DropDown

```
var classesList = this.GetClasses(Convert.ToInt32(CanalMassivo));
    var classesData = classesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = m.idSegmento.ToString(),
    });

    var states = classesData.Select(m => m.Value).ToList();
    return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Na parte `Value = m.idSegmento.ToString()` e o valor que aparece no DropDown quanto o valor que o controller recebe.

Como poderia fazer para passar a descrição no DropDown e o controller receber o valor do id ?

Tentei assim

```
        Text = m.descricao.ToString(),
        Value = m.idSegmento.ToString(),
    });

    var states = classesData.Select(m => m.Text).ToList();
```

Mas gera esse erro

```
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'idCanalIndicadoresMassivo'.
```

Comment: Poste como está sua `view` com o `DropDown`. Provavelmente você está utilizando `idCanalIndicadoresMassivo` quando deveria ser apenas `Value`.

Comment: Randrade, Obrigado. Poderia acessar aqui ? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100716/dropdown-cascata que tem todo o inicio do meu codigo, View, Controlle, Model, JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você quer utilizar o `SelectListItem()` altere sua action para isso:

```
var classesList = this.GetClasses(Convert.ToInt32(CanalMassivo));
    var classesData = classesList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = m.idSegmento.ToString(),
        Text = m.descricao
    });
    //Não selecione somente o texto, você precisará dos dois.
    return Json(states, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

E em sua chamada `ajax`, onde povoa o `DropDown`, você altera para passar o `idSegmento` no value e a `descricao` no `option`, desta forma:

```
   $.each(data, function (i, state) {
         //Create new option
         var option = $('<option value="'+state.Value+'">' +state.Text+ '</option>');
         //append state states drop down
         stateDropdown.append(option);
   });
```

Desta forma você irá visualizar a descrição, e o `DropDown` terá o value de `idSegmento`.

Comment: Randrade.! Perfeito.!! Muito Obrigado pela ajuda.!!